# Get next <div> with specific class and remove a class

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to write some jQuery so that when a `<div>` with a specific class (form-field) is selected, a subsequent `<div>`, with a different class (form-field-dropdwon) has another css class (hide) removed.

This is the html

```
             <div class="col-sm">
                <h2 class="section-title">
                  Header                    </h2>
                <input type="hidden" name="" value=""  />
                <div class="form-field">
                  Header <i class="fa fa-caret-down orange"></i>
                  <div class="form-field-dropdown hide">
                    <div class="select-option selected">
                      Option
                    </div>
                    <div class="select-option">
                      Option
                    </div>
                    <div class="select-option">
                      Option
                    </div>
                    <div class="select-option">
                      Option
                    </div>
                    <div class="select-option">
                      Option
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

And this is the jQuery I'm using:

```
<script>
    $(".form-field").click(function() {
        $(this).next().find(".form-field-dropdown").removeclass('hide');
    });
</script>
```

I've tried various versions of this but don't seem able to select the `<div>` I'm after.  Can you help?

Comment: Why .next()? You want to select a _child_ of `.form-field`, and not a _sibling_ of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your form-field-dropdown div is not the next sibling, so next() wont work,

Use find function to achieve this, so that it will find ".form-field-dropdown" inside the parent ".form-field"

```
<script>
    $(".form-field").click(function() {
        $(this).find(".form-field-dropdown").removeClass('hide');
    });
</script>
```

**Also its removeClass(), not removeclass(). C is in caps**

Answer (score 2):

There is no next() Element in your example code. Based on the structure of your code it looks like you want to find the `form-field-dropdown` directly inside the `form-field` class.

So the correct JS would be: `$(this).find(".form-field-dropdown").removeClass('hide')`

Does this solve your issue?

Comment: I've already tried this and it didn't work (and just did it again to confirm)

Comment: just realised I've misstyped `removeClass` as `removeclass`

Comment: Just a little typo: it should be `removeClass` instead of `removeclass`.

Answer (score 1):

`next()` gives you the next sibling of the element, which is not what you want. You want to find the element inside the current element (`this`). Just remove `next()` and it should work.

```
<script>
    $(".form-field").click(function() {
        $(this).find(".form-field-dropdown").removeclass('hide');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I've already tried this and it didn't work (and just did it again to confirm)

Comment: just realised I've misstyped removeClass as removeclass

Answer (score 0):

`.next()` is excess here. You just need to find child in this div:

```
$(".form-field").click(function() {
    $(this).find(".form-field-dropdown").removeClass('hide');
});
```

If it still doesn't work as expected so check up CSS to find some errors there. And check in Elements inspector, what happens inside your html.

Comment: `.next()` gives you next neighbour element, but not its children!